# How to create dynamic leader lines?

Tags: qgis, postgis, labeling, coordinates, dynamic-layer

I'm trying to create dynamic leader lines by using a PostGIS view in addition to the QGIS „Move Label“ tool.

```
CREATE VIEW leader_line AS
SELECT
gid,
ST_MakeLine(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(xcord_label, ycord_label), SRID))::geometry(linestring, SRID) AS geom
FROM point
WHERE xcord_label IS NOT NULL;
```

This works fine for all labels `WHERE ST_X(geom) < xcord_label` but creates wrong looking leader lines for labels `WHERE ST_X(geom) > xcord_label`.

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know how to get properly placed leader lines for labels `WHERE ST_X(geom) > xcord_label`? Is there any way to refer to the xmax coordinate of the labels?

[image]

Comment: are your labels in points or map units?If it's map units it should be fairly easy to guess the height, and thereby shorten your leader line to compensate)

Comment: The label size is in map units.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use QGIS' [quadrant](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html#moderate-fa-using-labels-instead-of-layer-symbology) placement specifier determined from the line's azimuth to place a better label. The quadrant specifies 8 positions around a point:

```
[ 0=Above Left | 1=Above | 2=Above Right |
  3=Left       | 4=Over  | 5=Right       |
  6=Below Left | 7=Below | 8=Below Right ]
```

Here's an example around [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island), creating a table and two views.

```
CREATE TABLE points (
  gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  geom geometry(Point, 4326),
  label_geom geometry(Point, 4326),
  label text
);

INSERT INTO points(geom, label_geom, label)
SELECT origin, pt, round(degrees(ST_Azimuth(origin, pt))) || ' degrees'
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 4326) AS origin,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(cos(radians(x)), sin(radians(x))), 4326) AS pt
  FROM generate_series(0, 350, 15) AS x
) AS f;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW point_labels AS
  SELECT gid, label_geom AS geom,
  CASE
    WHEN ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom) ISNULL THEN 2 -- default if azimuth cannot be determined
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 22.5 THEN 1 -- Above
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 67.5 THEN 2 -- Above Right
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 112.5 THEN 5 -- Right
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 157.5 THEN 8 -- Below Right
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 202.5 THEN 7 -- Below
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 247.5 THEN 6 -- Below Left
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 292.5 THEN 3 -- Left
    WHEN degrees(ST_Azimuth(geom, label_geom)) < 337.5 THEN 0 -- Above Left
    ELSE 1 -- >= 337.5 Above
  END AS quadrant, label
  FROM points;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW leader_line AS
  SELECT gid, ST_MakeLine(geom, label_geom)::geometry(LineString, 4326) AS geom, label
  FROM points;
```

Then in QGIS, add:

- `points` – `geom`
- `leader_line` – `geom` – primary key needs to be `gid`
- `point_labels` – `geom` – primary key needs to be `gid`

[image: QGIS]

Now configure the layer properties for `point_labels`:

- Change style so the point is not drawn, e.g., change size to 0.0
- Label this layer with `label`, and change placement to "Offset from point", modifying the "Quadrant" to use the attribute field `quadrant`

[image: quadrant]

Bingo!

[image: Bingo]

Note that a slightly different approach is required for `geography` types, since [ST_Azimuth](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Azimuth.html) behaves differently.

---

**Update:** When adding new points to the `points` layer, the `geom` field is updated as usual, but the `label_geom` is not. To populate a default value of `label_geom` with new points, a [trigger needs to be created](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html). But if a trigger function is used, the `quadrant` specifier can be stored in the `points` table and the `point_labels` view can be ignored:

For example, let's start again with a slightly different example with one table and one view:

```
-- DROP TABLE points CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE points (
  gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  geom geometry(Point, 4326),
  label_geom geometry(Point, 4326),
  quadrant integer,
  label text
);

CREATE FUNCTION label_geom_tg_fn() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  azimuth float8;
BEGIN
  -- Set a default label_geom
  IF NEW.label_geom ISNULL THEN
    NEW.label_geom := NEW.geom;
  END IF;
  -- Determine quadrant
  azimuth := degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, NEW.label_geom));
  NEW.quadrant := CASE
    WHEN azimuth ISNULL THEN 2 -- azimuth cannot be determined, so put Above Right
    WHEN azimuth < 22.5 THEN 1 -- Above
    WHEN azimuth < 67.5 THEN 2 -- Above Right
    WHEN azimuth < 112.5 THEN 5 -- Right
    WHEN azimuth < 157.5 THEN 8 -- Below Right
    WHEN azimuth < 202.5 THEN 7 -- Below
    WHEN azimuth < 247.5 THEN 6 -- Below Left
    WHEN azimuth < 292.5 THEN 3 -- Left
    WHEN azimuth < 337.5 THEN 0 -- Above Left
    ELSE 1 END;-- >= 337.5 Above
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER label_geom_tg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON points FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE label_geom_tg_fn();
```

The from the first example, re-do the `INSERT INTO points` and `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW leader_line` statements, as these do not require modification. But ignore the `leader_line` view.

Then in QGIS, add:

- `points` – `geom`
- `points` – `label_geom`
- `leader_line` – `geom` – primary key needs to be `gid`

Now configure the layer properties for `points` with `label_geom` as the first example did for `point_labels`. The `quadrant` specifier will be modified automatically for new and moved points, but you will only notice these changes each time you save your edits.

Comment: Great work, but how to add a new point feature in QGIS having two geometry columns in one PostGIS table?

Comment: @Lunar Sea - interesting, do you get two entries for the table, one per geometry, but qgis doesn't let you set the geometry field from the combo? Have you tried using a manual sql query in the import dialog box (it's the rightmost column, and often hidden out of view...)?

Comment: I've two 'points' layers in QGIS (`gid | label_geom | label` and `gid, geom, label`).

Comment: @LunarSea I reworked a second example that has one table and one view. The table has trigger functions to determine a default value for the `label_geom`, and also updates the `quadrant` value too, so the `point_label` layer/view is no longer needed.

Comment: Nice workaround Mike! After moving a `label_geom` I've to save the layer edit and refresh the canvas to see the actual position of the label. It's a pity that there is no way using a quadrant specifier with the QGIS "Move label" tool.

Comment: I got this to work today, but using a single view with 2 geometries - point (for the label from label_x, label_y) and line (makeline between original geom and label geom) - the view contains the quadrant as well, which worked great. The only issue I have is - our scenario would be to place labels dynamically, which involves a clunky workflow of moving the source labels, saving the edit, and seeing the leader and quadrant-placed label in the view on the map - again, clunky, but it does work! Unfortunately I'm going to have to use the ez custom labeler for this map...

Answer (score 1):

okay.. as it's in map units this should be fairly straight-forward, within limitations. You already know the height of the label. If it was in points it would be scale-dependant.

This assumes a fixed label size, so how well this works depends on how uniform your labels are, and whether or not you use a proportional or fixed-width font (fixed width is easier - multiply the length of the label by the label size to get the label width).

Sadly this doesn't answer your question on how to actually find the bounds of the label **as rendered**.

you have 4 cases (NE,NW,SE,SW).

i assume your table looks like this (apologies, some field names are different)

```
CREATE TABLE points
(
  uniq int PRIMARY KEY,
  geom geometry(Point,27700),
  label_x int,
  label_y int,
  labeltext character varying(100)
);
ALTER TABLE points
  OWNER TO user;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE points TO user;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE points TO public;
```

Next, add 4 points (all identical) but with labels in the 4 quadrants to represent the 4 main use cases

```
insert into points values 
(1,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(1000,1000),27700),750,750,'123');

insert into points values(2,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(1000,1000),27700),1250,1250,'456')

insert into points values 
(3,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(1000,1000),27700),750,1250,'456')

insert into points values 
(4,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(1000,1000),27700),1250,750,'789')
```

I used CRS 27700 (0,0 in lower-left, map units in m)
I've assumed a label width 50, height 30 map units.

```
-- SW use case
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW leader_line_sw AS
SELECT
uniq,
ST_MakeLine(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(label_x+50, label_y+30), 27700))::geometry(linestring, 27700) AS geom
FROM points
WHERE label_x IS NOT NULL AND 
label_y<=ST_Y(geom) and label_x<=ST_X(geom);

-- SE use case
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW leader_line_se AS
SELECT
uniq,
ST_MakeLine(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(label_x, label_y-30), 27700))::geometry(linestring, 27700) AS geom
FROM points
WHERE label_x IS NOT NULL AND 
label_y<=ST_Y(geom) and label_x>ST_X(geom);


-- NE use case
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW leader_line_ne AS
SELECT
uniq,
ST_MakeLine(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(label_x, label_y), 27700))::geometry(linestring, 27700) AS geom
FROM points
WHERE label_x IS NOT NULL AND 
label_y>ST_Y(geom) and label_x>ST_X(geom);

-- NW use case
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW leader_line_nw2 AS
SELECT
uniq,
ST_MakeLine(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(label_x+50, label_y), 27700))::geometry(linestring, 27700) AS geom
FROM points
WHERE label_x IS NOT NULL AND 
label_y>ST_Y(geom) and label_x<=ST_X(geom);
```

**Affine Transformations**

Another possibility is to shorten all leading lines, to say 80%.

- You could use ST_Translate(geom,-ST_X(geom),-ST_Y(geom)) to move the line to the origin to get geom_o
- use ST_Scale(geom_o,0.8,0.8) to get geom_o_scaled
- then retranslate using ST_Translate(geom_o_scaled,ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom)) back to the original position.

This might work better, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thank you for your effords, unfortunately the leader lines don't match the labels very well.