# Masking dynamic leader lines for pie charts in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, masking, transparency-opacity, leader-line, chart

I am trying to duplicate
the example in this post [Moving Pie Chart in QGIS and creating leader line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243058/moving-pie-chart-in-qgis-and-creating-leader-line#new-answer?newreg=fe16e1ba14dd45d3a0f5c65fe2748f89) with some modifications. I'm trying to combine this with transparency and I'd like to mask off the leader lines based on the pie chart size (so the line appears to connect to the circumference and not the center of each pie).

[image]

I think I need a masking solution because the pie chart size varies dynamically and is not always predictable (ie, there is a minimum size bound below which pies are presented at a particular size, but not a maximum size). Any ideas? QGIS 3.16

Comment: The have full control of all settings, you could create pie charts using geometry generator with the function `wedge buffer`. However, it's not so straightforward.